# Is it the correct behaviour of gulp.watch to run its tasks asynchronously

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am looking on gulp api documentation and I see the following under `gulp.watch()` documentation:

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['uglify','reload']);
```

I don't understand it. In case any js file changed, gulp runs uglify and reload. The thing is that uglify and reload run asynchronously! It might finish reloading before uglifying...

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a mistake, because you don't know the content of these tasks. Even if the name of the second can evoke the reload of the browser, it could be something else. I think the example is only here to demonstrate that a watcher can launch multiple tasks.

Though you're right, it can be very misleading when you don't know how gulp dependency chaining works, and this should be changed.

It has [been discussed](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/96) and finally will be implemented in gulp 4. The `runSequence` plugin is one of the best way to go to do what you want for now.

Comment: Why gulp will never implement this feature/?

Comment: My bad, I've forgot that this will be in gulp 4, you can see it in [this issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/96). Will edit my answer